# Reduce Margin of Button when the button is focused

Tags: wpf, controltemplate, wpf-4.0

I have a scenario where I want to reduce the margin of a Button control when it receives focus. This is because because I wan't to increase the border property of that Button control and at the same time wan't the button to stay same size (height and width). So a little bit of effort on web guided me to write a ValueConverter and get the margin reduced. But I am still not able to put up the working code till yet. Here is what I have jumbled up

Xaml

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers> <!--ControlTemplate for the Button-->
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="bdrButton" Value="Wheat"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="bdrButton" Value="2"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="bdrButton" >
                                <Setter.Value>
                                <Binding ElementName="bdrButton" Path="Margin" Converter="{StaticResource N_MarginReducer}">
                                        <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                            <Thickness>1,1,1,1</Thickness>
                                        </Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                    </Binding>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
    Thickness newMargin = new Thickness();
    Thickness margin = (Thickness)value;
    Thickness reduceBy = (Thickness)parameter;

    newMargin.Left = margin.Left - reduceBy.Left;
    newMargin.Top = margin.Top - reduceBy.Top;
    newMargin.Right = margin.Right - reduceBy.Right;
    newMargin.Bottom = margin.Bottom - reduceBy.Bottom;

    return newMargin;
}
```

The above code results in StackOverFlowException for the Margin.Left being called recursively. Anyone has better idea or implementation for the scenario that I am trying to achieve.

Comment: What's the reason for not trying to use the "LostFocus" and "GotFocus" events in the Button class?  Might be easier than an IValueConverter.

Comment: Leslie, Thanks for the reply, but can you please guide me how we could use it in this scenario. I don't wan't to use the code behind file following the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Yes that would not follow MVVM.  One thing after looking at your XAML though - it seems like the value for the Setter for bdrButton margin is not located within a Setter? Or your copy/paste went wrong.

Comment: Yes just a copy/paste devil. I have rectified my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use a ThicknessAnimation for the Margin and a DoubleAnimation for the height/width, rather than using a converter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.thicknessanimation.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation.aspx

Example:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Thickness x:Key="unfocusedThickness" Top="15" Left="15" Right="15" Bottom="15"/>
        <Thickness x:Key="focusedThickness" Top="5" Left="5" Right="5" Bottom="5"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button Height="100" Width="100" Margin="15">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.GotFocus">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="100" To="120" Duration="0:0:0"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="100" To="120" Duration="0:0:0"/>
                        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="{StaticResource unfocusedThickness}" To="{StaticResource focusedThickness}" Duration="0:0:0"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.LostFocus">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="120" To="100" Duration="0:0:0"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="120" To="100" Duration="0:0:0"/>
                        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="{StaticResource unfocusedThickness}" From="{StaticResource focusedThickness}" Duration="0:0:0"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
    <TextBox />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: The margin property will be coded differently for the different button so I can't hard code that. Even if I use the Element Binding to get the Margin to use in the "From" part of animation, I can't hard code any value in "To" part of animation as it will be the difference between "From" value of Margin and the BorderThickness that I have increased. I believe we can't use Maths to set the "To" property. Thanks for the reply. regards, Nirvan

Comment: Hold on for a moment, I think I can use the "By" part of animation. Will let you know soon.

Comment: That's just an example of how to do it in 1 case, you should be able to build off of it.  You could define a few Thicknesses as StaticResources and use them.  I'll update my example.